# Sockets: How to mask binary form of ip address using inet_pton()

Tags: c, sockets, binary, ip, bitmask

I'm looking for the correct way to use sockets to perform a mask operation on an ip address.  I attempted to convert the ip addresses to binary using inet_pton and then perform a binary and (&), but the compiler complains that I can't cast sin_addr to unsigned int.  Can someone please guide me to the correct method for doing this?

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
struct sockaddr_in maska;
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
// store IP address and mask in sockaddr structs:
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.0.2.33", &(sa.sin_addr));
inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.0", &(maska.sin_addr));

// Try to perform mask
sa.sin_addr = (unsigned long)sa.sin_addr & (unsigned long)maska.sin_addr;

// now get it back and print it
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: There's a lot more to a `sin_addr` than just a number. Pretty sure you're looking for something like `sa.sin_addr.s_addr = sa.sin_addr.s_addr & maska.sin_addr.s_addr;`, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it than that.

Comment: @ WhozCraig Thanks.  Yeah, I was looking for a socket function that performed a masking op and returned the masked address, but I haven't found anything with that functionality.  Your method works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is resulting because you are assigning `sa.sin_addr` as if it is an `unsigned long` when it is a `struct in_addr`.

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;
    unsigned short   sin_port;
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;
    char             sin_zero[8];
};
```

You should use the member containing the address.

```
struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;
};
```

Change this line:

```
sa.sin_addr = (unsigned long)sa.sin_addr & (unsigned long)maska.sin_addr;
```

to this:

```
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = sa.sin_addr.s_addr & maska.sin_addr.s_addr;
```